# Condition variables and mutex_unlock

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

Code:

```
void *inc_func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
void *watch(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv,&mutex);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t id[2];
    pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,watch,NULL);
    pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,inc_func,NULL);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
}
```

Now we have one `mutex_unlock` function to be executed in each thread. And one locked mutex. Why doesn't this lead to an `undefined behaviour`. Since both threads try to unlock the same mutex which leads to one trying to unlock an already unlocked mutex.

Edit: `pthread_cond_wait` releases the `mutex` for the second thread to use. Now consider the second thread executes `pthread_cond_signal` which leads to the first thread to reacquire the `mutex`. Now we have two threads having the same `mutex` lock,because both didn't get to execute the `mutex_unlock` because of the 'sleep' function. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: This question is possible duplicate. Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778780/if-you-unlock-an-already-unlocked-mutex-is-the-behavior-undefined

Comment: Showing some example code would definitly help to not misunderstand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `pthread_mutex_lock()` blocks if the mutex to be locked is already locked. It returns if the mutex got unlocked.
- `pthread_cond_wait()` unlocks the mutex when starting to wait and locks is before returning. Returning might get delayed if the mutex in question is still locked. Returning then will be delay until the mutex got unlocked.

Putting the above together and applying it to the code you show one sees that each thread function nicely starts with a locking followed by an unlocking (and so on), so everything is fine.

Referring to the example code: `pthread_cond_wait()` returns when `inc_func()` had called `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.

---

To successfully handle the scenario described by the example code you need to consider two special cases

1. the case of signal coming first and
2. the case of so called ["*spurious wake-ups*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup), that is `pthread_cond_wait()` returning without having been signalled.

To handle both such case each condition should have a watch variable.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = ...
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv = ...

int signalled = 0;

void *inc_func(void *arg)   
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
  signalled = 1;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  
}

void *watch(void *arg)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  while (0 == signalled)
  {
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv,&mutex);
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t id[2];
  pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,watch,NULL);
  pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,inc_func,NULL);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
}
```

Comment: I rephrased the question better I think

Comment: @InQusitive: You wrongly assume that `pthread_cond_wait()` returns due to `pthread_cond_signal()` having been called. This is not the case.

Comment: There cannot be two threads holding the same mutex per definition. Thats what they are for. `pthread_mutex_lock()` will simply block if called on an already locked mutex, would not return. @InQusitive

Comment: @InQusitive: Did your real code initilaise the mutex it uses? Does your real code check the outcome of each `pthread_*()` function called, tests whether it perhaps failed?

Comment: Yes, Anyway my understanding was wrong about the mutex_cond_wait. Now it is clear. :) Please put your second comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If indeed the order is

- `watch` runs first and locks (while `inc_func` waits)
- `watch` which has the mutex waits using `pthread_cond_wait` which unlocks the mutext and blocks as per the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html)

> These functions atomically release mutex and cause the **calling thread
>   to block** on the condition variable cond;

This allows the following

- `inc_func` acquires the mutex then signals (at this point the mutex is yet to be released)
- `inc_func` releases the mutex
- Because the mutex was released and the mutex unlocked the execution of `watch` resumes having locked the mutex as per the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html):

> Upon successful return, the mutex has been locked and is owned by the calling thread.

- What follows is a legal release of the mutex.

The scenario that you did not consider is what if the code of `inc_func` executes first without switching to `watch`

- `inc_func` locks the mutex
- `inc_func` signals but there's no one to be signaled, which is OK.
- `inc_func` unlocks the mutex
- `watch` locks the mutex
- then waits for the conditional variable but there will be no one to signal it so it'll wait forever.